Значение приставки "при"
Каково значение приставки "при" в этих словах - "неполнота действия" или "совершение действия в чьих-то интересах"?

Принарядить(ся)
Приодеть(ся)


ПРИОДЕТЬ, -одену, -оденешь; приодень; приодетый; -одет, -а, -о; св.
кого. Разг.

Одеть в красивую одежду, принарядить. П. дочку к празднику. Со вкусом п. детей.

ПРИНАРЯДИТЬ, -ряжу, -рядишь; принаряженный; -жен, -а, -о; св. Разг.

Надеть что-л. нарядное на кого-л. П. невесту. П. дочь на праздник.


В словаре не фиксируется "неполноты", как в случаях с "приоткрыть" или "притормозить", поэтому склоняюсь к тому, что приставка характеризует чьи-либо интересы.


Центральным значением приставки ПРИ является обобщенное значение ПРИБЛИЖЕНИЯ к предмету, признаку или действию, которое частным образом может выражаться как: расположение около предмета, направленность на предмет, присоединение или добавление к предмету и др. Также значения приставки ПРИ при неполном действии можно рассматривать как приближение к основному действию, открыть — приоткрыть, тормозить — притормозить.

Каково же значение приставки ПРИ в слове принарядить?. Это надо смотреть по словарю.
ОДЕТЬ,  св. кого-что (во что, чем). 1. Облечь в какую-л. 
одежду (противоп.: раздеть). О. малыша на улицу. О. 
больного для прогулки. О. куклу. 

ПРИОДЕТЬ, св. кого. Разг. 1. Одеть в красивую одежду, 
принарядить. П. дочку к празднику. Со вкусом п. детей.

НАРЯДИТЬ,  св. кого-что (во что). Нарядно, красиво одеть. 
Н. невесту. Н. детей в новые костюмчики. Н. в шелка и 
бархат. Н. ёлку (украсить новогоднюю ёлку).

ПРИНАРЯДИТЬ, св. Разг. Надеть что-л. нарядное на кого-л. 
П. невесту. П. дочь на праздник. 


Одеть — это просо облачить в одежду. Приодеть — одеть в красивую одежду, принарядить (разг.). И дальше значение не меняется: нарядить  — нарядно, красиво одеть (нейтр.), принарядить — одеть что-то нарядное (разг.)

Таким образом,  приставка ПРИ добавляет к одежде  нечто красивое уже в глаголе приодеть, и тогда это значение добавления, как и в глаголах рисовать — пририсовать, дать — придать, соединить — присоединить . Значения направленности к чему-либо  или неполного действия нет. В то же время имеется в виду, что красивая одежда одевается обычно по случаю праздника или другого события.



А что насчет совершения действия в интересах?

Это глаголы вида:  беречь – приберечь, прятать – припрятать.  Там интерес указывается конкретно: ПРИБЕРЕЧЬ,  св. что. Сберечь, сохранить, оставить про запас до какого-л. случая. П. деньги на покупку. ПРИПРЯТАТЬ,  св. что. Разг. Спрятать, скрыть; убрать про запас. П. деньги. А в глаголе принарядить такой обязательной направленности нет.  Например: Детей принарядили и вывели к гостям.

То есть одели в красивую одежду.  Вариант разговорный, но нейтральный глагол нарядили сюда не подойдет. Возможно, приставка ПРИ все-таки имеет причинное значение: почему одели красиво. Но в словаре это не отражено.

Получается, что глагол принарядить не такой уж разговорный, если не заменяет нейтральный по семантике. И тогда можно считать, что направленность есть или может быть: принарядили ради гостей или ради праздника.
